# C# How can i hide my app in the background?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, background

Im making an android app and i would like to make it run in the background without letting it ever pause and i don't want the user to see it... for cientifical purposes... Anyone has any info on this matter?

Comment: Impossible, Android will never allow this for security reasons

Comment: @Nickolaus Its possible to run apps in the background that's what i need to know how to do then the background or paused lifecycle stuff is ignored if the code is running in another thread so i really just need to know how to background it.

Comment: Do you mean after the user has already started the app, or are you trying to start the app in the background without the user noticing?

Comment: @AgileNinja Start in the background if possible.

Comment: @TheReptilianArmy yeah, that's not possible

Comment: @AgileNinja hmm Alright thanks anyways ^^

Comment: "i don't want the user to see it" --> this is impossible android will not allow it for security reasons as I said before ... running an application in background is no problem, BUT the system can not guarantee it stays alive... the Java-Garbage collector will clear the memory if it feels the need to do this,.... activities in the background will be paused or stopped if the system needs the memory or the cpu power

Comment: @Nickolaus What if i set the priority of the app to the max will it still clear it?

Comment: Yes it does not matter you can't guarantee it stays running, activities in the background are designed to be killable by the system at any time therefore the service component has been defined

Comment: @Nickolaus Ugh android not malware-friendly qq

Comment: Yeah as programmer you should not produce malware.... so don't wonder that android tries to prevent this....

Comment: @Nickolaus Its all for science bro

Answer (score 3):

You can not **hide** an app in the background, but you can create a background service that is defined within your app:

Common items are:

- The service lifecycle.
- Threading.
- Controlling service restarts due to service shutdown by the system under memory pressure.
- Simplifying service development using the IntentService class.
- Notifying users.

I highly recommend starting here as Xamarin multi-page article overviews all the different different Android service types and the pro/cons:

[Xamarin Android / Creating Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/)